# Dismissing keyboard on specific fields

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this library in my Swift app to include a custom picker view rather than the default one: https://github.com/kirkbyo/Dropper

I have the library setup and working properly as it is intended to. On the same view that I am using this custom picker, I have a few text fields. When I add a function to dismiss the keyboard if the user clicks away from the keyboard, this library stops working properly, you cannot select any of the items in the drop down.

Here is what I have to dismiss the keyboard:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

- How do I get this to work without breaking the custom picker library?
- Can I limit the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the specific text fields?
- Can I get the keyboards to dismiss when the user taps the "Return" key instead?

Comment: Have you tried, textField.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: Where would I place this?

Comment: Wherever you want to dismiss the keyboard. For example in your dismissKeyboard function.

Comment: Thanks, this works on the text fields, but causes the library to not work :(

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: When I try to select an element in the dropdown created by the Dropper library, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you added view.endEditing(true) anywhere in your code or maybe? Or is it working before you do textField.resignFirstResponder?

Comment: The library works perfectly when I do not include view.endEditing(true) or textField.resignFirstResponder. When I include either of them, the library does not work

Comment: Could it be this part that is causing it? let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Comment: try adding a semicolon after dismissKeyboard inside the quotes, see where that gets you

Comment: That caused the app to crash and gives me this error: dismissKeyboard;]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: That should not be needed @DanBeaulieu since she does not have any parameters in the dismissKeyboard function.

Comment: Check my answer @KatieH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `textField.resignFirstResponder` instead of `view.endEditing(true)` in the `dismissKeyboard` function. Regarding the problem with the selector in the library, try to add the the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the entire view and if that don´t work try to add it to the dropdown view only.

**Update**

I downloaded the library and this worked for me, to hide the dropper on tap.

```
func dismissKeyboard(){
    if dropper.status != .Hidden {
       dropper.hideWithAnimation(0.1)
    }

    self.txtField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

**Update 2**

The problem was that the UITapGesture was covering the entire view, so I added the delegate for the UITapGusture and added some exceptions.

So do this:
Add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your class, so it looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Add the delegate to your tap gesture

```
tap.delegate = self
```

And add this in your extension

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view!.isKindOfClass(UIButton) || touch.view!.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) || touch.view!.superview!.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And you should be good to go :)

Comment: How do I add UITapGestureRecognizer to the entire view?

Comment: If your view is "view" as you have entered in your code example then you have done it already. Otherwise just check what your view is called and NAMEOFVIEW.addGestureRecognizer(tap).

Comment: I really appreciate your help, this is not working. Why do you think the library conflicts with the UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: You mean that when you tap on the view the dropper is still visible or? Check the update that will help you with that if you mean that problem.

Comment: Thank you!! Now the dismissing of the keywords works, but in the dropdown nothing actually selects. Take a look at the function: extension ViewController: DropperDelegate {
    func DropperSelectedRow(path: NSIndexPath, contents: String) {
        /* Do something */
        
        print("it worked!")
    }
}

Comment: The dropdown simple disappears after clicking an element. I think we are soooo close! :)

Comment: Okey I´ll check, 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Your gesture recognizer might interfere with your custom picker touch.

Try to identify that by tap and hold the custom picker selection for a few second, if it is working, then the gesture recognizer is surely interfere with your custom picker delegate function.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourCustomPickerView]) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```